# поиск по регулярным выражениям c++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++11

Добрый день.

Есть строчки типа

```
"C:\users\downloads\1.txt""1460577050""63f9fa2d3e3b5bc31cc3663e4cc7167f1d763c6fa880943e5995fda8a34bd030"
```

пытаюсь по регулярному выражению вытаскивать все то, что в кавычках. Использую примерно такое регулярное выражение:

```
regex mask("\"{1}['_'' ''\\'':''.'[:alnum:]]+\"{1}");
```

но оно пропускает путь, как выяснил методом тыка, ей что-то не нравится в слэшах.

Что исправить, для получения нужного результата?

Comment: в кавычках у вас две пустых строки, однако

Comment: Не увидел, где именно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если в кавычках не может быть удвоенных кавычек ("") и формат строк не меняется, то можно [сделать так](https://regex101.com/r/vP0iI1/1):
`^"([^"]*)""([^"]*)""([^"]*)"`

Comment: А если там будет четыре элемента внутри кавычек? 5, 6 ?

Comment: ... то это надо указывать в вопросе.

Comment: Там будет только 3 элемента.
Мне больше интересно как это вставить в значение выражения, на тупое подставление ругается.

Comment: `"\"([^\"]*)\"\"([^\"]*)\"\"([^\"]*)\""` - так тоже ругается?

Comment: В общем, немного изменил вариант маски:

    regex mask("\"([^\"]*)\"");
так она вытаскивает то, что надо, поочередно с помощью regex_search, спасибо)